# Does Eliyahu like dogs?

Tags: sources-mekorot

Is there a source of the teaching "that a house with a dog is not visited by Eliyahu HaNavi?" Is a Jew allowed to own a dog or not?

Comment: Sion, welcome to Mi Yodeya! Could you please [edit] in more information about where you've heard this teaching? That would be very helpful to potential answerers. Also, could you please [edit] in why you suspect that this teaching may lead to a practical prohibition? Finally, please note that "Like any library, Mi Yodeya offers tons of great information, but *[does not offer](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734) personalized, professional advice*, and does not take the place of seeking such advice [from your rabbi](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146)."

Comment: it might be regarding a single woman

Comment: According to Bava Kama 60b dogs like eliyahu. כלבים משחקים, אליהו הנביא בא לעיר.

Comment: See http://www.kipa.co.il/ask/show/34098-%D7%90%D7%9D-%D7%99%D7%A9-%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%91-%D7%91%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%90%D7%96-%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95-%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%99%D7%90-%D7%9C%D7%90-%D7%91%D7%90-%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA where the question was asked. The Rav never heard of the idea that Eliyahu Hanovi does not visit a house with a dog.

Comment: You seem to be asking two separate, but related, questions. 1) Does Eliyahu not visit a house with a dog? 2) Is it allowed to own a dog? I would recommend splitting them up.